# Where do Brambles/Briars/Thickets Grow?

Tags: flora, natural-growth

I'd like to have a region in my world be a predominately hilly, karst style (so lots of limestone) area that has a predominance of thick, dense thickets, brambles and shrubs.

So my question is, what soils/climates/biomes/etc... do thickets and briar style growth grow best in (in order to achieve a dense landscape of such) and can this match up with a hilly, karst landscape?

Can thickets of briar and brambles feasibly grow in a karst style limestone landscape?

Comment: [Garrigue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garrigue). [Mattoral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matorral). [Maquis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maquis_shrubland). [Chaparral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaparral). The general term is [scrubland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrubland) or shrubland.

Comment: Thank you these are helpful! But I am looking for more septic info concerning briar thickets

Comment: Am I dreaming or is this one of those "let me google that for you" moments?

Comment: We'd need to know what the worldbuilding context is to answer properly. The PH is a bit high on limestone for brambles to thrive, you might consider gorse instead, however if this doesnt suit you we need to know much more about the context so we can find something that does. Voting to put on hold until you can [edit] to fill us in.

Comment: In New Zealand, it grows every blimmin where. Blackberry, Barberry, Hawthorn, and Gorse are all plants that are considered invasive pests and grow from sea level to alpine in any place trees aren't established. If you simply said "there was a lot of brambles on the cliff" I doubt any reader would doubt that it could happen.

Comment: @elemtilas It is but the rules say questions that can be answered by an easy Google search don't count as against the rules of Worldbuilding SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my home state of Oregon we have Himalayan blackberries that grow all over the western 1/3 of the state, including in the Coast Range which has some marine sediments. But viney brambles like blackberries are generally fairly thirsty, and karst geologies usually have very good drainage, so you'd probably need to have frequent rainfall and a fairly temperate climate. Otherwise, more shrublike plants with deep root systems and smaller leaves would be likely to colonize these areas (see: Oregon's eastern 2/3rds, which has almost no blackberries).

Source on blackberry growth conditions: https://www.fs.usda.gov/Internet/FSE_DOCUMENTS/stelprd3828954.pdf

Comment: Thank You! This gave me just the info I needed!